# Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class: simplexmlelement

Tags: php

I'm using this php script

```
$error = false;
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', $_POST['username']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    if(file_exists('users/' .$username . '.xml')){
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('users/' .$username . '.xml', 0, true);
        if($password == $xml->password){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: agis-employees.html');
            die;
        }
    }
    $error = true;
}
```

And I end up with this error

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate
>   non-existent class: simplexmlelement
>   in
>   /home/virtual/site250/fst/var/www/html/employeeportal/index.php
>   on line 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This most likely means that the SimpleXML extension is not enabled/present in your PHP installation. You can verify this by executing `phpinfo()` and looking for 'SimpleXML'. See:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php